# Use api.ai intents in botbuilder

Tags: node.js, botframework, dialogflow-es

API.ai's prebuild packages allow you to easily get long lists of intents. Currently I'm trying to make use of their `smalltalk` package, which has at about 100 intents, and response to each.

I am making use of the `api-ai-recognizer` package to listen for intents. That works well, but now I have to match those intents, so that I can define the dialog (which is nothing more than using the fulfillment). And this is where I am having trouble.

```
intents = IntentDialog({recognizers: [apiairecognizer(CLIENT_TOKEN)]})
intents.matches('smalltalk', smalltalk_handler) // No luck
intents.matches(/smalltalk/, smalltalk_handler) // No luck
intents.onDefault(default_handler)
```

In the default_handler I capture the `args`:

```
{"score":1,
 "intent":"smalltalk.greetings.how_are_you",
 "entities": [
   {
     "entity":"Lovely, thanks.",
     "type":"fulfillment",
     "startIndex":-1,
     "endIndex":-1,
     "score":1
   },
   {
     "entity":false,
     "type":"actionIncomplete", 
     "startIndex":-1,
     "endIndex":-1,
     "score":1
   }
 ]}
```

This makes sense according to the documentation of how [matches](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.intentdialog.html#matches) works.
But that does mean that I don't know how to actually use the full list of intents, without explicitly copying every single intent in.

Just to clarify, if I use the exact intent:

```
intents.matches('smalltalk.greetings.how_are_you', smalltalk_handler)
```

I receive the nice response: `Lovely, thanks.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only thing I have come up with is to modify the `api-ai-recognizer` such that it will return only `smalltalk` as intent, whenever it encounters a version of it. This way the intent dialog only needs to recognize one intent. Because they are handled in the same way, it doesn't matter at this point.